# Abstracted Dispose Method not called when using nSubstitute

Tags: c#, unit-testing, abstract-class, nsubstitute

i have this base (abstract) class:

```
public abstract class StreamWriterBuilderService : IStreamWriterService
{
    private Stream fs;
    private StreamWriter stream;

    public void WriteLine(
        string stringToWrite )
    {
        if ( stream == null )
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException( "Tried to call WriteLine on an uninitialised StreamWriterBuilderService" );
        }

        stream.WriteLine( stringToWrite );
        Flush();
    }

    public void Flush()
    {
        if ( stream == null )
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException( "Tried to call Flush on an uninitialised StreamWriterBuilderService" );
        }

        stream.Flush();
    }

    public void Initialise(
        string filePath )
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>( filePath != null );

        fs = File.Open( filePath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite );
        stream = new StreamWriter( fs );
        WriteLine("Initialised");
        Initialised = true;
    }

    public bool Initialised { get; private set; }

    #region Dispose Implementation

    ~StreamWriterBuilderService()
    {
        Dispose( false );
        Debug.WriteLine( false, "This StreamWriterBuilderService object was not disposed of" );
    }

    private bool _isDisposed;

    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose( true );
        GC.SuppressFinalize( this );
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(
        bool disposing )
    {
        if ( _isDisposed )
            return;

        if ( disposing && Initialised )
        {
            stream.Dispose();
            fs.Dispose();
            stream = null;
            fs = null;
        }

        _isDisposed = true;
    }

    #endregion Dispose Implementation
}
```

I am unit testing this with:

```
    protected readonly string TargetFilePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
    protected const string Header = "Initialised";

    protected override void SetContext()
    {
        SUT = Substitute.For<StreamWriterBuilderService>();
    }
```

and...

```
    private string fileContents;
    private const string TestString = @"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!£$%^&*()+~@?><|¬";

    protected override void Because()
    {
        base.Because();
        SUT.Initialise( TargetFilePath );
        SUT.WriteLine( TestString );
        SUT.Flush();
        SUT.Dispose();
        fileContents = File.ReadAllText( TargetFilePath );
    }
```

The trouble I am having is that this:

```
SUT.Dispose();
```

does not actually call my Dispose method in my abstract class because it is declared as a virtual method.  If I remove the virtual method then the code is played out. However, I need to keep the virtual method there as I need to override elsewhere in my solution...

Comment: Given the standard pattern does not specify `virtual` on the parameterless Dispose(), can you talk us through why you added it? https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/dispose-pattern

Comment: @mjwills Thanks for posting. Well i have not added it. It was already there. (work).  But, if the abstract class needs to dispose of things and if any child class may also need to dispose of things then surely I would need to use virtual so I can call its base and the childs dispose?  Always like to learn.. what would you advise as an alternative?

Comment: @mjwills Thanks. Sorry i was multi-typing :) did not notice the link  durrhh.. thanks will read now +1

Comment: @mjwills quire right. Not sure why that virtual keyword was added. Removed it 
(thanks). However, The Dispose(True) does not call the virtual method in this scenario.  I may have to use a concrete class off this base instead :(

Comment: @mjwills But how?  the base is used with the nsubstitute.for and not as a base

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
var SUT = Substitute.ForPartsOf<StreamWriterBuilderService>();
```

This gives you [fine control](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/partial-subs/) over the specific things you want to substitute. *Thus, by default, your `Dispose` methods won't be substituted.*

Alternatively, my recommendation (for this specific scenario) would be to build your own `StreamWriterBuilderServiceForTesting` class (that inherits from `StreamWriterBuilderService`). *Because NSubstitute would not be involved, you could define its behaviour however you like.*

Comment: Not sure what happened to my previous comment, I had said 'thanks for your answer. I had used the latter. But had not realised the former would do what I want to'. With reflection I would have deleted this question as it seems a simple answer.  I was just looking in the wrong places. thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you `substitute` a class like this, the *virtual* methods are replaced by the substitute. You probably want a partial substitute replacing only `Dispose(bool)`.

[Documentation about partial substitutes](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/partial-subs/)

and [the second Paragraph here](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/creating-a-substitute/):

> For starters, NSubstitute can only work with virtual members of the class, so any non-virtual code in the class will actually execute!

That is, virtual methods will *not* execute.

I'd create a derived type for testing purposes just to remove the `abstract`, and then test with that.

Comment: Can be done with `ForPartsOf` substituting `Dispose(bool)`, if you don't want to substitute anything, just use the original class (or derive trivially from it if it's `abstract`)

Comment: Haukinger - Thanks. I am readings docs now.  If you have an answer you could post then..  :)